# Is there any reason to create views programmatically instead of using interface builder?

Tags: ios, iphone, interface-builder

I have seen that some teams require to create every view programmatically using tools like Masonry, etc. And I am wondering, what is the reason of that. I have always thought that IB is a really fast and easy way to create views and layout.

Could you please specify all the pros and cons of using programmatic approach instead of IB?

Comment: This is an opinion based question. There are strong feelings on both sides of this topic. I come down strongly on the "do everything possible in IB" camp. Some people believe in doing everything by hand. (I think of this as "Macho programming". To me it seems like insisting on doing everything in assembler to show how tough you are. Sure, you can do that, but **why?**

Comment: If you are working alone and don't want to spend too much time on creating views go for IB .

Comment: Code -> Long time to develop, less conflicts on source control, everything in 1 file.  IB -> Quick development, more conflicts and more places to look for when you want to calculate whats going on in a view.

Comment: You just opened a can of worms here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual arguments are summed up nicely [in this post](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/why-i-dont-use-interface-builder):

> I have spent countless hours searching for the source of a bug only to discover it’s some checkbox in one of the half dozen inspectors in Interface Builder. If it was in code, it’s simple to glance at the view code and see the source of the problem much quicker.

I haven't really found that to be true overall. There are occasions, particularly with auto layout, where it is often true.

> If you use Interface Builder and have outlets and forget to connect the outlet in the second place you use it, you crash at runtime. This is terrible. This introduces a whole new class of bugs.

Happens, but defensively programming to detect them with asserts in `viewDidLoad` isn't that hard.

> Have you ever had a merge conflict in a NIB. It’s the worst. (Granted the XIB format has helped, but it’s just awful instead of impossible now.) If you’re working in a large application with several developers, you will waste an enormous amount of time dealing with this issue.

This one is a **very** solid argument indeed. Storyboards were a *crippling* pain point for that until we had references, now it's merely often annoying. Code diffs and histories **FAR** better than Interface Builder will ever do.

> Every time I get a crash while editing a NIB, I grumble to myself and wish it was code even more.

That used to be a great argument. There's still a few rough edges you learn to avoid, but it's a mediocre argument these days.

> Layout code is not hard. Auto-layout is a bit more code than traditional layout, but it’s still not bad. Trying to work with auto-layout in Interface Builder is maddening. Setting outlets to control built-in constraints is just silliness.
>
> It’s so simple to just override layoutSubviews and do your thing. Personally, I find this much easier to work with than auto-layout for most things.

This was unreservedly true a couple years ago. It's better now, and stack views have made a *lot* of pain just disappear, but it's still a pain point.

> Interface Builder itself is not bad. It does encourage bad practices, prevents reusability (making working with others more difficult), and slows your workflow.

That it makes working with others more difficult is a solid point, doubt anyone who's worked on a large project would disagree as merging edits to Interface Builder files is next to effectively impossible. The rest ... arguable, at best.

Answer (score 0):

It's all depends on requirements. For example If you want to add some views on button's click then you have to add it programmatically.

There is no performance difference between both either added programmatically or added in Interface builder.

The difference is that by interface builder it's become very easy compare to programmatically and that's why apple provide interface builder to make it more developer friendly and simple otherwise everything can done by code only.

So, it's better to use IB when possible because it's too much easy and simple and very less time taking.

Answer (score 0):

It all about your choice. I prefer programmatically. 
Reason-

- `Xcode` generally hangs when you try to open `XIB` or `storyboard` in big projects with multiple targets.
- `Smaller` project size.
- Easier to debug `view heirarchy.`
- View being dynamic, then there is no point creating it in XIB.
- It's easy to resolve conflicts when creating view programmatically.
- A very good article about how apple creates views: [Apple NIB](https://www.quora.com/Do-serious-design-focused-developers-use-Interface-Builder)

You should work with mix approach.